# Oracle SQL Select from a Large Number of Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere (There has to be something out there on the topic), but I can't seem to find a concise answer to my question.

I am relatively new to SQL, and when I have worked with it I have only used basic statements.  Now I am working with a pretty large database (in Oracle) and was asked to explore it a little bit on the development side to get more familiar.

One of the questions that was sent to me to explore the db involved finding a list of "Run Controls" that are associated with a particular user.

There is a single table that keeps track of the different types of "Run Controls" that exist via a field titled `run_cntl_id`. There are 18 rows in this table associated with the specific user, each with a unique `run_cntl_id`.  For each of the values in the `run_cntl_id` field, there is at least one corresponding table with multiple rows (pretty standard database stuff).  Unfortunately, I do not have any reference material to display the table relationships.

There are just under 3,000 tables that contain both the `oprid` (the user identifier) and the `run_cntl_id` (the type of "Run Control") fields (when they are separated, there are 3,100 tables that contain the `run_cntl_id` field, and 8,800 that contain the `oprid` field).  There are approximately 65,000 total tables in the database.  Is there a way to search these 3,000 tables for the specific `operid` and `run_cntl_id`?

If I wanted to perform this query on one table, I would use the following statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PS_JRNL_COPY_REQ
WHERE oprid = 'jle0010'
AND run_cntl_id = 'Copy_Jrnl';
```

To rephrase the question:

Is there a way to perform this statement on the 3,000 tables mentioned above without running a single statement 3,000 times?

Comment: This seems like a major design flaw. Technically, you can query 3000 tables with one statement - but most likely it would be a dynamic sql statement that union-alls all of these tables. I would even consider chances of Oracle failing to parse it.

Comment: Sorry, did you just say you had 65 _thousand_ tables in your database. Are you sure?

Comment: Haha, I'm 100% positive.

Comment: How many times will you need to run these queries?  If only a few times then you should just hack together a few large strings.

Comment: 65,000 is around the number of objects that can be referenced by a single PL/SQL program unit, and I'd not be surprised if a query against them all exceeded the (vaguely documented) limit on the size of an individual SQL statement. Probably someone thought this design was a great idea back when there were only 20 customers/users, instead of 3,000.

This sounds like it needs a major refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the 3,000 tables have the same columns then your query is going to look like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (
  select * from PS_JRNL_COPY_REQ union all
  select * from other_table_1    union all
  select * from other_table_2    union all
  ... and so on for 2,997 more)
WHERE oprid = 'jle0010'
AND run_cntl_id = 'Copy_Jrnl';
```

No guarantees on it parsing or running though.

You can build that inline view by querying user_tables of course.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I'm going to risk it... I'll try to find a better solution.  I'll probably post another related question soon.